# How to list all bibliography entries in r-markdown, sorted by year, in descending order (anti-chronological)

Tags: r, sorting, r-markdown, bibliography, citations

Is there any instruction to be issued in the YAML header block to simply have all the bibliography entries sorted by year in descending order, i.e. starting from the more recent?

Here is my MWE:

```
---
title: "My Report"
output:   html_document
bibliography: biblio.bib
nocite: '@*'
---

# R Markdown
some text

# References
**I'd want them sorted by year, in descending order, i.e. starting with the most recent**
```

to be used with a biblio.bib file (example taken from here: [Rmarkdown nocite does not display citations in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709989/rmarkdown-nocite-does-not-display-citations-in-pdf)):

```
@inproceedings{wuthrich2008modelling,
  title={Modelling the claims development result for solvency purposes},
  author={W{\"u}thrich, Mario V and Merz, Michael},
  booktitle={Casualty Actuarial Society E-Forum},
  pages={542--568},
  year={2008}
}


@article{wuthrich2009uncertainty,
  title={Uncertainty of the claims development result in the chain ladder method},
  author={W{\"u}thrich, Mario V and Merz, Michael and Lysenko, Natalia},
  journal={Scandinavian Actuarial Journal},
  volume={2009},
  number={1},
  pages={63--84},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}


@article{merz2007prediction,
  title={Prediction error of the expected claims development result in the chain ladder method},
  author={Merz, Michael and W{\"u}thrich, Mario V},
  journal={Bulletin of Swiss Association of Actuaries},
  volume={1},
  number={2007},
  pages={117--137},
  year={2007}
}
```

As noted, I want to use the '@*' command to cite all the bibliography,  and the sorting type I'm looking for is the 'ydnt' .